# How I can write SQL for not in this case

Tags: sql

I want to criteria these condition in picture from my table but I can't do it

[image]

I have a table `TotalOrder_export` with all the information.

I write some condition but it does not work, can anyone help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're problem is with the `case` statement in your `where` clause?

Although I would guess the entire query could be rewritten and optimized more, to answer your specific question, you could just use an `or` statement.  Here's a condensed version (could have included all of it if you had included code versus the image):

```
select ...
from ...
where ... and 
   ([mat group1 des] != 'PPW Ream' or [Sales Doc No] not in (...))
```

Comment: I try this but it not work bec when i write PPW ream, the result ok but when i criteria PPW Roll, the result =0

Comment: @monte -- I was just fixing your existing error in your query.  You'll need to continue your existing logic to get your desired results.

Comment: so if i want to use case in my query ,for case PPW REAM and PPW ROLL, could you please advice me again